# Take a row from 2D vector and make it into new int?

Tags: c++, vector, new-operator

I have the following 2D array

```
54 65 22 34 11
43 12 44 22
```

I have the following vector syntax:

```
vector<vector<int>> data;

vector<int> row_1 = data[0]; // return 54 65 22 34 11
vector<int> row_2 = data[1]; // return 43 12 44 22
```

Is there a way I can make the row_1 and row_2 vector into this:

```
int *row_1 = new int[5] // return 54 65 22 34 11
int *row_2 = new int[4] // return 43 12 44 22
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you traverse through the vector in a loop and store into the row_1/row_2?

Comment: Sorry, how should I write it to achieve that? New to this whole C++ and only started this month.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with `row_1` and `row_2` once in that form.   `std::copy(data[0].begin(), data[0].end(), row_1)` will copy the elements from `data[0]` to the dynamically allocated array pointed to by `row_1`.   The behaviour will be undefined if you have not allocated enough elements.    Bear in mind that pointers have no information about the number of elements allocated using `new []`, so you need to pass that information around to use the pointer (or risk accessing elements past its end).

Comment: Generally speaking, however, you generally should not do manual dynamic allocation.   There are few advantages and numerous disadvantages of using pointers to dynamically allocated memory in this way.    The circumstances where you *need* to do this (e.g. passing the pointer AND the size to a function which accepts those arguments, which is compiled as C) do exist, but in C++ are often best avoided.

Comment: Thanks Peter. What I am trying to achieve here is to use the integers in the vectors to do some conditional checks and to sort it eventually. In my original program, I asked the user to input their integers using 'new'. Since there is a slight change now, I am not sure how to obtain all the integers from a row in the vector to do my existing conditional checks and sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the vector is the same as the new int array you are trying to store it as. Probably best to allocate it with row_1 vector size:

```
vector<int> row_1_vec = data[0]; // return 54 65 22 34 11
vector<int> row_2_vec = data[1]; // return 43 12 44 22

int* row_1 = new int[row_1_vec.size()];
int* row_2 = new int[row_2_vec.size()];
```

Now traverse through the vector:

```
for(int val = 0; val < row_1_vec.size(); val++)
{
  row_1[val] = row_1_vec[val];
}

for(int val = 0; val < row_2_vec.size(); val++)
{
  row_2[val] = row_2_vec[val];
}
```

Make sure when you are done using row_1 and row_2 to delete it by doing

```
delete[] row_1;
delete[] row_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `new[]` at all in what you're trying to achieve.

Usage of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and `std::istringstream` to parse each integer from the input is all that's required.

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> vRow;
   std::string line;
   int num;
   while (std::getline(cin, line))  // get a line of data
   {
      // add an empty row to the vector 
      vRow.push_back({}); 

      //parse the numbers   
      std::istringstream strm(line);
      while ( strm >> num )
         vRow.back().push_back(num);  // add new number to last row added
   }

   // Output results
   for (auto& v : vRow)
   {
      for (auto& v2 : v )
        std::cout << v2 << " ";
      std::cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/9jD8od)

If you later want to sort the first row, for example, you do this:

```
std::sort(vRow[0].begin(), vRow[0].end());
```